# rake db:migrate failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, abort

I've just started to study Rails.
When I try "rake db:migrate", the following error occured.

> rake aborted!
>   FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "kt1"

it seems there's something wrong with database.yml but I have no idea how to solve.
Please give me an advice.

---

Thank you very much for your comment and edit. I'm using postgresql (0.13.2). My environment is as follows.
Ubuntu 11.10
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.2.3
gem 1.8.21

database.yml as below.

---

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On Mac OS X with macports:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: kt1_development
  pool: 5
  username: kt1
  password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # The server defaults to notice.
  #min_messages: warning

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: kt1_test
  pool: 5
  username: kt1
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: kt1_production
  pool: 5
  username: kt1
  password:
```

---

I also tried with username in blank. Then the error comes to

```
rake aborted!
FATAL:  role "kenji" does not exist
```

(kenji is my username on Ubuntu.)

Comment: Could you post your `database.yml`? Blocking out any sensitive data. What database type (MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.) are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first [create the user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-createuser.html) kt1 , then [create the database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdatabase.html) and give the user permission to it.

There is a way to let rails create the user and database, but in postgresql, it is best to do it by hand (IMHO)

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Last night I tried to do what you suggested and made it. It was not easy as I'm very beginner of postgresql so I tried as many ways as I can find, and finally I succeeded.

Answer (score 10):

Try to modify your (`/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/`) `pg_hba.conf` file like this, changing the method for local users from peer to trust.

```
# Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
local   all         postgres                          trust

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

Comment: Yes, that will work. May be a good time to also study all the other Postgres authentication methods.

Comment: Thanks, man! I've spent several hours, fighting this problem. Your advice helped me!

Comment: Make sure to run `sudo service postgresql restart` after making this change for it to work!

Answer (score 0):

look at your database.yml file, in there will be the database adapter, possibly a database name, a username  and password.

The adapter tells you which database system you are using,  sqllite3, mysql2, whatever

See if you can manually connect to that database system using the username and password that are contained in the database.yml.  Once you figure out the correct user name and password to manually connect,  update database.yml with any changes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the application was built with sqlite intially, and then ported to Postgres so as to be hosted on Heroku.

Running rake db:migrate was gives you the following errror

`PGError (FATAL: role "rails" does not exist ): error message.`

And rspec spec/ and rake cucumber fails with similar errors.

The following steps seem to solve the problems:

Create rails as a super user: 
`createuser -s rails`
(Note: If you did not setup yourself as a DB superuser, you'll need to specify a different DB user to do this as. For me it was createuser -s rails -U postgres)

Create the database with owner rails as specified in database.yml :

`createdb -O rails kt1` (As in step 1, if you need to specify a different DB user to do this as, add -U )

After this rake db:migrate, rspec spec/ and rake cucumber should run successfully.